# How to set the default download folder for uGet in Windows?

Tags: download-manager, uget

I am using uGet to download files and it downloads all my files into "C:\Users\Joe"

I need to download the files into D:\Downloads

I can't find such a setting in the general settings options (Edit - Settings)

I went to Category - Properties - Default for new download 1 and I set the Folder to "D:\Downloads"

but still, when I download using File - Batch Downloads - "Text file import (.txt)" or "URL Sequence batch", I still get my files in C:\Users\Joe

Comment: Did you try the UGET Chrome wrapper for configuration?  This was a later addition to UGET.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011881/how-to-change-default-downloader-on-firefox

Comment: File -> New download. Enter your default folder to the Folder box. Enter a URL. click ok. Try downloading another file(s) (New download or Batch Downloads), it should be downloaded to your preferred folder.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - you are right, it works. Can you add your reply as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

1. Go to File -> New download.
2. On the Folder box, enter your default folder.
3. Enter a URL to a file to download. Click OK.
4. Try downloading another file(s) via New download or Batch Downloads. It will be downloaded to your preferred folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a logical design. The default download path should not be hidden in the dialog for a particular download. There should be a direct setting for that.

If we customize a folder for a particular download, uGet should revert to default folder for the next download.

Of course, a checkbox can be provided to remember this folder path for all subsequent downloads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155494)